# Bug in my recursive division algorithm (to generate maze randomly)

Tags: javascript, html, maze

I'm having trouble generating a random maze. My algorithm creates the initial box where the maze will be. But I cannot seem to generate any walls inside of this box. I'm trying to use the recursive division algorithm. Here is my code:

```js
class Maze {
    constructor(COLS,ROWS) {
        this.width = COLS;
        this.height = ROWS;
        this.COLS = this.width*2+1; // *2 To account for blocks which are replaced by walls, 
        this.ROWS = this.height*2+1; // so the hollow blocks will be half of the total blocks, and there 
        //will be +1 wall (because the border of the maze will be a wall on either side on both x and y axies.)
        this.dimentions = [this.COLS, this.ROWS];
        this.maze = this.initArray([]);

        // This will palce the border walls (the ones on the outside of the maze)
        this.maze.forEach((currentRow, index) => {
            if(index === 0 || index === this.ROWS-1) {
                currentRow.forEach((_, cellIndex) => {
                    this.maze[index][cellIndex] = ["BLACK_WALL"];
                });
            } else {
                this.maze[index][0] = ["BLACK_WALL"];
                this.maze[index][currentRow.length-1] = ["BLACK_WALL"];
            }
        });

        // Now do the "recursive division" method to generate the maze
        const randomWallStart = [[2,2], [this.COLS-3, this.ROWS-3]][this.randInt(0,2)]; // Picks top left or bottom right
        const randomWallEnd = [[this.COLS-3, 2], [2, this.ROWS-3]][this.randInt(0,2)]; // Picks the other corner
        this.recursiveDivision(randomWallStart, randomWallEnd);
    }

    randInt(min, max) { // Used in random generation of maze
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min))+min;
    }

    initArray(value) {
        return new Array(this.ROWS).fill().map(() => new Array(this.COLS).fill(value));
    }

    recursiveDivision(wallStart, wallEnd, its=0) {
        this.maze[wallStart[1]][wallStart[0]] = ["FLAG1"];
        this.maze[wallEnd[1]][wallEnd[0]] = ["FLAG2"];
        const randXpoint = this.randInt(wallStart[0], wallEnd[0]); // Doesn't matter which way round the max and min are.
        const randYpoint = this.randInt(wallStart[1], wallEnd[1]);

        const directionToBuildWall = wallStart[0] === wallEnd[0] ? 0 : 1; // 0 = x-axis 1 = y-axis

        const newWallStart = [randXpoint, randYpoint];
        let forwardsOrBackwards = 1;
        if(newWallStart[directionToBuildWall] > this.dimentions[directionToBuildWall]/2) {
            forwardsOrBackwards = -1;
        }

        let currentPosition = newWallStart;
        currentPosition[directionToBuildWall] +=  forwardsOrBackwards * 1;

        while(this.maze[currentPosition[1]][currentPosition[0]] != "BLACK_WALL") {
            this.maze[currentPosition[1]][currentPosition[0]] = ["BLACK_WALL"];
            currentPosition[directionToBuildWall] += forwardsOrBackwards*1;
        }

        if(its > Math.min(this.COLS-2)) {
            return;
        }
        const beginningPos = currentPosition.slice();
        beginningPos[directionToBuildWall] = 1; 
        this.recursiveDivision(currentPosition,beginningPos,its+1);

    }

  posToSpace(x) {
    return 2 * (x-1) + 1;
  }

  posToWall(x) {
    return 2 * x;
  }

  inBounds(r, c) {
    if((typeof this.maze[r] == "undefined") || (typeof this.maze[r][c] == "undefined")) {
      return false; // out of bounds
    }
    return true;
  }

  isGap(...cells) {
    return cells.every((array) => {
      let row, col;
      [row, col] = array;
      if(this.maze[row][col].length > 0) {
        if(!this.maze[row][col].includes("door")) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    });
  }

  countSteps(array, r, c, val, stop) {

    if(!this.inBounds(r, c)) {
      return false; // out of bounds
    }

    if(array[r][c] <= val) {
      return false; // shorter route already mapped
    }

    if(!this.isGap([r, c])) {
      return false; // not traversable
    }

    array[r][c] = val;

    if(this.maze[r][c].includes(stop)) {
      return true; // reached destination
    }

    this.countSteps(array, r-1, c, val+1, stop);
    this.countSteps(array, r, c+1, val+1, stop);
    this.countSteps(array, r+1, c, val+1, stop);
    this.countSteps(array, r, c-1, val+1, stop);
  }

  display() {
    this.parentDiv = document.getElementById("maze-container");
    while(this.parentDiv.firstChild) {
      this.parentDiv.removeChild(this.parentDiv.firstChild);
    }
    const container = document.createElement("div");
    container.id = "maze";
    container.dataset.steps = this.totalSteps;

    this.maze.forEach((row) => {
      let rowDiv = document.createElement("div");
      row.forEach((cell) => {
        let cellDiv = document.createElement("div");
        if(cell?.join) {
          cellDiv.className = cell.join("");
        }
        rowDiv.appendChild(cellDiv);
      });
      container.appendChild(rowDiv);
    });

    this.parentDiv.appendChild(container);

    return true;
  }
}

const myMaze = new Maze(5,5);
myMaze.display();
```

```css
body, html {margin: 0;}
#maze-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#maze {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #a7c53f;
  background-size: 8em 8em;
}
#maze div {
  display: flex;
}
#maze div div {
  position: relative;
  width: 1.2rem;
  height: 1.2rem;
}
#maze div div::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: -3px;
  top: -4px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px black;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  z-index: 10;
}
.FLAG1 {
    background-color: #a00;
}
.FLAG2 {
    background-color: #0a0;
}
#maze div div.BLACK_WALL, #maze div div.nubbin.BLACK_WALL, #maze div div.door.exit {
  background-color: #000;
  background-size: 0.5em 0.5em;
}
#maze div div.nubbin.BLACK_WALL::after {
  content: "";
}
#maze div div:nth-child(odd) {
  width: 1em;
}
#maze div:nth-child(odd) div {
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="maze-container"></div>
```

As you can see when you run the code, the walls are generated, but in the wrong places. So some touch each other (so you can't move between them) and I cannot solve this problem.
I cannot get this "*recursive division*" algorithm to work properly.

Comment: is this what you are trying to build? https://jmhero05.medium.com/maze-generation-with-depth-first-search-and-recursive-backtracking-8f846b80d62d

Comment: Please explain more precisely which recursive algorithm you are implementing. What is the significance of the FLAG1 and FLAG2 CSS classes? Have you stepped through your code, inspecting variables and monitoring where it first goes wrong?

Comment: @trincot The recursive alg. is [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Recursive_division_method), and the FLAG1 and 2 classes are for debugging purposes, they show between which points the wall will be placed. I can't figure out how it goes wrong, as when I print the variables to the console, everything seems fine and logical. But the maze isn't.

Comment: The referenced algorithm places its wall gaps at random places, while yours seems to put the gaps at the extreme end of a wall. Also the referenced algorithm sets walls between cells, not like your algorithm which occupies cells with walls, often resulting in walls that are adjacent with no room between them. Again, I don't recognise much of the referenced algorithm. Do you really want to implement that referenced algorithm? Then you need to start from scratch I am afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least these issues in your code:

- The wall is built at a random position without taking into account the odd/even division of your cells in potential-wall / not-wall cells (which is the reason why you had `this.COLS = this.width*2+1` in the constructor). As a consequence your walls can end up adjacent to eachother, leaving no room for open cells. You should only place horizontal walls at *even* Y-coordinates, and vertical walls at *even* X-coordinates.
- The door in the wall is always made at the extreme end of the wall, while the algorithm should make the gap in that wall randomly.
- There is only one recursive call, which means the algorithm is not aware of the fact that a wall generally divides the room into two partitions, each of which should (generally) be further divided up through recursion. So you need two recursive calls instead of one.

If you correct those points it could work. However, I prefer a data structure where really **each** inner array element represents a cell, and the walls are inferred by properties of those cells. So, no cells will function as wall. Each cell then can track which are its neighbors (4 at the most). A wall can then be implemented by *removing* a neighbor from a cell (and doing the same in the reverse direction). The visualisation of a wall can then be done with `border` CSS styling.

Here is an implementation:

```js
class Maze {
    static Cell = class {
        constructor(x, y, left, above) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.neighbors = [left ?? null, above ?? null, null, null];
            // Also set link in opposite direction
            if (left) left.neighbors[2] = this;
            if (above) above.neighbors[3] = this;
        }
        
        block(direction) { 
            // Place a wall by clearing neighbor link
            if (this.neighbors[direction]) this.neighbors[direction][direction ^ 2] = null;
            this.neighbors[direction] = null;
        }
    }
    
    constructor(parent, numCols, numRows) {
        this.parentDiv = parent;
        
        let above = [];
        this.maze = Array.from({length: numRows}, (_, y) => {
            let left = null;
            return above = Array.from({length: numCols}, (_, x) => left = new Maze.Cell(x, y, left, above[x]));
        });
        this.recursiveDivision(0, 0, numCols, numRows);
    }


    recursiveDivision(left, top, right, bottom, its=0) {
        const randInt = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

        const width = right - left;
        const height = bottom - top;
        // Base case: cannot be divided further:
        if (width < 2 || height < 2) return; 
        let choice = randInt(0, (width - 1) + (height - 1));
        if (choice >= width - 1) { // Place horizontal wall
            const y = top + choice - (width - 2);
            const gap = randInt(left, right);
            for (let x = left; x < right; x++) {
                if (x != gap) this.maze[y][x].block(1);
            }
            this.recursiveDivision(left, top, right, y, its+1);
            this.recursiveDivision(left, y, right, bottom, its+1);
        } else { // Place vertical wall
            const x = left + choice + 1;
            const gap = randInt(top, bottom);
            for (let y = top; y < bottom; y++) {
                if (y != gap) this.maze[y][x].block(0);
            }
            this.recursiveDivision(left, top, x, bottom, its+1);
            this.recursiveDivision(x, top, right, bottom, its+1);
        }
    }

    display() {
        this.parentDiv.innerHTML = "";
        const container = document.createElement("div");
        container.className = "maze";
        for (const row of this.maze) {
            const rowDiv = document.createElement("div");
            for (const cell of row) {
                const cellDiv = document.createElement("div");
                cellDiv.className = ["left", "top", "right", "bottom"].filter((_, i) => !cell.neighbors[i]).join(" ");
                rowDiv.appendChild(cellDiv);
            }
            container.appendChild(rowDiv);
        }
        this.parentDiv.appendChild(container);
    }
}

const myMaze = new Maze(document.getElementById("maze-container"), 30, 10);
myMaze.display();
```

```css
body, html { margin: 0 }
#maze-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.maze {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #a7c53f;
    background-size: 8em 8em;
}
.maze div {
    display: flex;
}
.maze div div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    width: 1.2rem;
    height: 1.2rem;
}
.left { border-left: 1px solid black }
.right { border-right: 1px solid black }
.top { border-top: 1px solid black }
.bottom { border-bottom: 1px solid black }
```

```html
<div id="maze-container"></div>
```